# Save output of a command execution with subprocess

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

I am trying to get output of `subprocess.Popen` in variable.
It is working fine for `pwd` command, but not working for `pwdx $(pgrep -U $USER -f SimpleHTTPServer)` command.

This works:

```
(Pdb++) p = subprocess.Popen("pwd", stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
(Pdb++) result = p.communicate()[0]
(Pdb++) result
'xyz'
```

This is not working:

```
(Pdb++) subprocess.Popen("pwdx $(pgrep -U $USER -f SimpleHTTPServer)", stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
*** OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Can someone please let me know how can I save the output of it to a variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to pass a command with arguments to `Popen()`, you have to pass it as a list, like so:

```
subprocess.Popen(['/bin/ls', '-lat'])
```

If you just pass a single string as in your example, it assumes the entire thing is the command name, and obviously there is no command literally named `pwdx $(pgrep -U $USER -f SimpleHTTPServer)`.

Comment: Thanks, I broke the command into multiple ones and could resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) and previous answers already state the command you want to execute via subprocess.Popen() needs to be passed as a **list**.

From the docs:

> Note in particular that options (such as -input) and arguments (such
>   as eggs.txt) that are separated by whitespace in the shell go in
>   separate list elements, while arguments that need quoting or backslash
>   escaping when used in the shell (such as filenames containing spaces) are single list elements.

Another useful tip you can get from the docs is to use `shlex.split()` to help you to properly split your command into a list.

Beware though that the use of special shell parameters (e.g. `$USER`) might not work well with subprocess.Popen() unless you would set the `shell=True` option, which you shouldn't do without reading the doc's [Security Considerations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#security-considerations).